# Check user web3.eth.accounts[0] value inside asp.net mvc action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web3js, metamask

How can I make sure inside my MVC action that the passed parameter string address is currently equal to JS `window.web3.eth.acccounts[0]`?

```
public ActionResult myAction( string address)
{
  if(address == // there should be check js window.web3.eth.acccounts[0])
{
   // other code
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Its a simple comparison... whats the issue?

Comment: Hi, I want to make user been able to change nickName on my asp.net website.
But I can't use User.Identity to check user identity because I simly checking if user logged into Metamask or not without using login or password on my website.
So I need the way to chek that user logged into Metamask in current time and have same address as user with nickName incide my mvc action.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as a parameter to your action like:

```
public ActionResult myAction(string address, string eth3Info)
{
    if(address == eth3Info)
    {
        //do the work
    }
}
```

but honestly this won't make much sense as both things are coming from client side and can be easily manipulated.

You should have some backend call to get the `window.web3.eth.acccounts[0]` information from source.

Comment: This is not much of an answer but easier to format as answer instead of comment so here we go!